# Scatter plot with alpha still opaque on areas where spots are dense

Tags: python, matplotlib, alpha, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot which is plotting a very large number of dots from two different data sets.  In some areas, there are vast numbers of dots, so that even with a very low alpha (e.g. alpha=0.1) you can't see through the mass.  But at that alpha, you can barely see the dots in the sparse regions.  Is there a way to bound the alpha for stacked dots or somehow make the background visible under the dense regions while not washing out the sparse regions?

The code snippet looks like this:

```
# Code to populate the datasets not included.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x1, y1, s=12, color='red')
ax.scatter(x2, y2, s=12, color='blue', alpha=0.1)
# Plus code to do xlabels and such not included.
```

to produce this:

[image]

As you can see, it is hard to see the bounds of the bottom red leg, and still make the top blue leg punch out.

Is there any way to create this effect?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

One good suggestion seems to be to use hexbin instead of scatter.  This does seem promising, but the colors still don't blend nicely.  For example,

```
ax.hexbin(x1, y1, cmap='Reds', mincnt=1, vmax=100)
ax.hexbin(x2, y2, cmap='Blues', mincnt=1, vmax=50, alpha=0.8, linewidths=0)
```

yields:

[image]

It would be really nice to make those blues and reds merge.  Maybe each pixel could have an R value from one dataset, and a B value from another dataset or something?  But it doesn't seem to be an option in hexbin.

EDIT

After applying Thomasillo's answer:

[image]

Thanks, I think it looks better than the original.

Comment: You might consider using hexbin instead, as shown in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html).

Comment: @BrenBarn how is hexbin useful here? It is a two-group density. I also did not understand if the example to which you linked was supposed to address this particular point.

Comment: You can use two hexbins, just as you are currently using two scatters.  If you use different colormaps for the two hexbins, and set both alphas to some non-opaque value, then you can get two hexbins that overlap in places.  I don't think a scatter (even with alpha) is the best choice for a data set with this much overlap.

Comment: One solution I can think of is to draw each dot individually, and change its alpha value based upon how many dots are near it within a certain radius.(nearest neighbor?) Of course this would require you to check each dot against every other dot O(n^2) and would require you to fiddle with a distance count function which then you would need to create an alpha value based upon(which is a lot of work that shouldn't need to be done). Also it would vary if you changed your plot width/height

Comment: I'd try contour plots of the density -- which means calculating density as the hexbins are doing, but sometimes is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In order to improve the hexbin plot, you can use the option bins='log'. This calculates the color of the hexagonal binning logarithmically, effectively making lower numbers stick out better compared to high ones.

2) Calculate the density for each dataset yourself. And from both densities generate a color by e.g. letting one density influence the red, and the other the blue channel. Plot the result using imshow.

Something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools

x1 = np.random.binomial(5100,0.5,51100)
y1 = np.random.binomial(5000,0.7,51100)
x2 = np.random.binomial(5000,0.5,51100)
y2 = np.random.binomial(5000,0.7,51100)


xmin,xmax,xnum = 2350,2700,50
ymin,ymax,ynum = 3350,3700,50
xx,yy=np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:xnum*1j,ymin:ymax:ynum*1j]

def closest_idx(x,y):
    idcs    = np.argmin((xx-x)**2 + (yy-y)**2)
    i_x,i_y = np.unravel_index(idcs, (xnum,ynum) )
    return i_x,i_y

def calc_count( xdat,ydat ):
    ct = np.zeros_like(xx)
    for x,y in itertools.izip(xdat,ydat):
        ix,iy = closest_idx(x,y)
        ct [ix,iy] += 1
    return ct

ct1 = calc_count( x1,y1 )
ct2 = calc_count( x2,y2 )

def color_mix( c1 , c2 ):
    cm=np.empty_like(c1)
    for i in [0,1,2]:
        cm[i] = (c1[i]+c2[i])/2.
    return cm

dens1 = ct1 / np.max(ct1)
dens2 = ct2 / np.max(ct2)

ct1_color = np.array([1+0*dens1 , 1-dens1 , 1-dens1  ])
ct2_color = np.array([1-dens2   , 1-dens2 , 1+0*dens2])

col = color_mix( ct1_color , ct2_color )
col = np.transpose( col, axes=(2,1,0))


plt.imshow( col , interpolation='nearest' ,extent=(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax),origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to plot my scale in log space but the result was nice.  I'll post it in my question so you can see.